# Spring AOP with Spring Webflux after authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-aop, aspect

I have a Enabled Spring AOP for my logging purpose and use webflux for the API entrypoint,
things work fine if the api does not go through `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` like my `login` api but the moment It has to go through `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` it throws the bellow exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No MethodInvocation found: Check that an AOP invocation is in progress and that the ExposeInvocationInterceptor is upfront in the interceptor chain. Specifically, note that advices with order HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE will execute before ExposeInvocationInterceptor! In addition, ExposeInvocationInterceptor and ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation() must be invoked from the same thread.
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:74) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.ums.api.contoller.Controller#getAllUser() [DispatcherHandler]
```

my AOP class

```java
public class LoggerAspect {

    @Pointcut("within(com.ums..*)")
    public void logEveryFunction() {
    }

    @Before(value = "logEveryFunction()")
    public void log(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("Entering function {} in location {}", joinPoint.getSignature(), joinPoint.getSourceLocation());
    }

    @After(value = "logEveryFunction()")
    public void logEnd(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("Exiting function {}", joinPoint.getSignature());
    }
}
```

authentication function

```java
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(authentication.getCredentials().toString())
                .map(value -> {
                    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            authentication.getName(),
                            null,
                          Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("VIEW"))
                });
    }
```

how can I make my AOP work with webflux and how can I fix the issue?

Comment: I cannot answer this question straight away, as I do not have any experience with reactive programming. But maybe I can figure it out, if you post a minimal reproducer on GitHub and post a link here. I need something reproducible.

Comment: i modified some online code, this should be enough i presume https://github.com/crazycatMyopic/issue-

Comment: You did yourself the biggest favour by providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please keep up this practice. It helps community members to reproduce your problems and yield better answers faster. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us read the error message again:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No MethodInvocation found:

Check that an AOP invocation is in progress and that the
ExposeInvocationInterceptor is upfront in the interceptor chain.

Specifically, note that advices with order HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE will execute
before ExposeInvocationInterceptor! In addition, ExposeInvocationInterceptor
and ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation() must be invoked from the
same thread.
```

So let us try by adding an `@Order` annotation to our aspect. But first, some research. You can check the Javadocs, I simply checked the source code:

```java
public @interface Order {
  int value() default Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
}
```

```java
public interface Ordered {
  int HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  int LOWEST_PRECEDENCE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  int getOrder();
}
```

Conclusion: The default order is `LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`, i.e. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Therefore, let us just assign a higher precedence, i.e. something smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. For your simple example on GitHub, any of the following will do: `@Order(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)`, `@Order(0)` or whatever you determine to be appropriate in your situation. Having added that to your aspect class, the caller will see this on the console:

```
$ curl -L "http://localhost:8080/login" -H "Authorization: Bearer ghfjhgf"
HI
```

The Spring server log will say:

```
[  restartedMain] c.a.s.SpringBootWebfluxJjwtApplication   : Started SpringBootWebfluxJjwtApplication in 1.646 seconds (JVM running for 2.156)
[  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
[  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
...
[oundedElastic-1] c.a.s.rest.LoggerAspect                  : Entering function Mono com.ard333.springbootwebfluxjjwt.rest.AuthenticationREST.login() in location org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint$SourceLocationImpl@641fcca3
[oundedElastic-1] c.a.s.rest.LoggerAspect                  : Exiting function Mono com.ard333.springbootwebfluxjjwt.rest.AuthenticationREST.login()
```

---

**Update**, responding to this follow-up question:

> I still wonder why did it happen, why was `@Order` required? There is only one advice (from my AOP) which other would be running?

If you remove `@PreAuthorize` from your login method that returns a `Mono`, it works without the `@Order` annotation on the aspect. That gives you a clue: Spring Security also seems to use AOP or at least some kind of method interceptor. Let us look at the actual error in more detail:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No MethodInvocation found: Check that an AOP invocation is in progress and that the ExposeInvocationInterceptor is upfront in the interceptor chain. Specifically, note that advices with order HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE will execute before ExposeInvocationInterceptor! In addition, ExposeInvocationInterceptor and ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation() must be invoked from the same thread.
  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:74) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
  Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.ard333.springbootwebfluxjjwt.rest.AuthenticationREST#login() [DispatcherHandler]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
  |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/login" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:74) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.getJoinPointMatch(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:658) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice.before(AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice.java:44) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAdviceReactiveMethodInterceptor.proceed(PrePostAdviceReactiveMethodInterceptor.java:156) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAdviceReactiveMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$4(PrePostAdviceReactiveMethodInterceptor.java:116) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
(...)
```

Please note `org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAdviceReactiveMethodInterceptor` in the stacktrace. Obviously, in Spring Security there is a special method interceptor for reactive methods. As described in the error message you and I posted before, this interceptor seems to require a special ordering of the interceptor/advice chain. I guess, it is some kind of bootstrapping problem, which users who wish to combine Spring AOP, Spring Security and WebFlux need to accommodate to.

Comment: this worked like a charm, Thank you, but I still wonder why did it happed, why was `@Order` required? there is only one advice (from my AOP) which other would be running?

Comment: Please note my update.

Comment: thank you for considering my follow up question as well, this was really helpful.  